# Replace Nulls of Struct type column using Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a use case where I want to replace nulls in **StructType** columns with empty values.
Below is sample which you can use to recreate the scenario:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType

data = [(1, [1, "Aman"]), (2, [2, "Raman"]), (3, [3, "Baman"]), (4, None)]

schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField("ID", IntegerType(), True),
        StructField(
            "Name",
            StructType(
                [
                    StructField("NameID", IntegerType(), True),
                    StructField("FirstName", StringType(), True),
                ]
            ),
            True,
        ),
    ]
)

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

df.show()
```

I want to know how we can replace nulls in `Name` column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `when` expression:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "Name",
    F.when(
        F.col("Name").isNull(),
        F.struct(
            F.lit(None).alias("NameID"), #replace None by default ID value if needed
            F.lit("").alias("FirstName")
        )
    ).otherwise(F.col("Name"))
)

df1.show()
#+---+----------+
#| ID|      Name|
#+---+----------+
#|  1| {1, Aman}|
#|  2|{2, Raman}|
#|  3|{3, Baman}|
#|  4|  {null, }|
#+---+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with [`coalesce`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce):

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "Name",
    F.coalesce(
        F.col("Name"),
        F.struct(
            F.lit(None).alias("NameID"),
            F.lit("").alias("FirstName"),
        ),
    ),
)
```